# How to match multiple enum cases in switch-statement on tuple?

Tags: swift, enums, tuples

I have a switch statement that check a tuple.  One of the part of the tuple is an `enum`.  How can I match multiple `enum` cases inside that tuple?

I've tried several things, which all lead to compiler errors.  Here's one attempt:

```
switch (enumValue, myArray.isEmpty)
{
case (.one, true):  // Fine.
    ...

case ((.one, .two), false): // Error: Tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'MyEnum'
     ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case is expecting a Tuple `(Enum, Bool)`. However, `((.one, .two), false)` is of type `((Enum, Enum), Bool)`, so what you should write is the following:

```
case (.one, false), (.two, false):
```

Comment: Ah indeed, what was I thinking :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't match multiple enum cases inside the tuple, you need to specify each enum case in a separate tuple. Alternatively, if you only care about the `Bool` value being `false` regardless of the `enum` case, you can use `case (_, false):`,

```
case (.one, false), (.two, false):
  ...
case (_, false):
  ...
```

Comment: Ah indeed, what was I thinking :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to repeat the whole pattern again:

```
switch (enumValue, myArray.isEmpty)
{
    case (.one, false), (.two, false):
     ...
}
```

If you don't like this, you can try making your enum less flat - grouping similar cases together. So rather than:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case one, two, three
}
```

you do:

```
enum OneOrTwo {
    case one, two
}

enum MyEnum {
    case oneOrTwo(OneOrTwo), three
}
```

Though you may not always find good names for these groups :(

Comment: Ah indeed, what was I thinking :-). Thanks!